# How can I have a web site automatically open up at a certain time each day

Tags: windows, website

We Have a web site that employees must check into at a specific time each day. How can I make the site automatically open on each users computer at a certain time each day.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could set Windows Scedule task that opens a the link to the website.

And push the task trough your windows server with a GPO for each of your computer on the network.

Answer (score 5):

What specifically do you need the users to do?

- Open the page?
- Read the page?
- Read and submit a response?

If the first, a simple scheduled task should suffice, as suggested by the accepted answer.

But if the second or third? Then you're a bit longer off.

Unfortunately there is no way to force someone to read the page, since for all you know, the person you expect to read it might not even be near the computer at that time.

And if you don't require anyone to read it, or can't guarantee that anyone will read it, why exactly do you need *everyone* to open that page then?

Sounds like a process with a flaw to me, to be honest.

Questions to ponder:

- What if the user has his machine on, but isn't around at that time? (gone for coffee, or even gone for the day, forgot to log off and turn off his computer)
- What if the machine is off at that time? What was the user expected to do on the website that he won't be doing that day

  - He could have just left
  - or he could arrive at work after the fact
- What if the user initiated a shutdown just as the page pops open? (race condition)

Answer (score 3):

You could keep it simple with [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569). Just create a shortcut to IE and add the URL to the shortcut.

Comment: Such a task should use whatever the user has set as their default browser, unless there is an overwhelming reason to use a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

Threaten the employees with termination if they don't.

Simply opening a website at a certain time every day will accomplish nothing. I'd treat it just like I treat a popup ad that gets past Firefox's adblock plugin - closing it before it ever gets a chance to load.

If it's truly vital to your business that people check this page every so often, it should be noticeable if no one checks it, and there should be a consequence for not doing it.